# What are $3 $2 in coderay/redcloth/textile/markdown?

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain what `$3` and `$2` this syntax are when using coderay?

http://railscasts.com/episodes/207-syntax-highlighting?view=comments

```
  require 'coderay'
  def coderay(text)
    text.gsub(/\<code( lang="(.+?)")?\>(.+?)\<\/code\>/m) do
      content_tag("notextile", CodeRay.scan($3, $2).div(:css => :class))
    end
  end
```

I've also seen `$4`. Where are these defined, and what do they reference, and is there documentation for it?

I don't even know what the proper question is to ask about these. Basically... what are they? I must understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are created by `gsub`, and called "captures". They will have the contents of what is matched by the parentheses in the regular expression. In your example, `$1` will be what matches `lang="(.+?)"`, `$2` will be the match for `.+?` inside the lang attribute, and `$3` the match for the other `.+?`, the tag contents. More precisely, `$1` is a special global variable that will be identical to `Regexp.last_match[1]`, which is, in turn, the same as `Regexp.last_match.captures[0]`. Similarly for the others.

You can find the Regexp-related special global variables reference in [`Regexp` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables).

It has nothing to do with CodeRay/RedCloth, and everything to do with regular expressions and core Ruby.

Comment: is `$1` referring to the first question mark, and `$2` the second, and so on? That doesn't seem likely because I have two question marks, but $3 and $2 are used

Comment: No, the first (second, third...) pair of capture parentheses. `(..)` are capture parentheses; `(?:..)` are not, neither are `(?=..)` (or several kinds more). Read `Regexp` reference to learn more.